# JQuery - How to send a form and call a anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a issue with a form - the form makes a validation without reload the page and print on screen the error only after I click the send button.

The issue occurs because the error message appears only on top of the form.

then if you are using small devices and small screens - the top and the send button does not appears in the same screen.

if the form has an error - and you click send - you cannot see the message and the form doesn't go anywhere.

for correct this I need to leave the screen at the top of the form again, after click the submit button

I tried putting a anchor id on the top, and create a

```
<a href="#topform"><button type="submit"></a>
```

or

```
<button type="submit" onclick="document.href:#topform">
```

but this doesn't Works. any idea?

Comment: so you want to submit the form by using top anchor button. correct ?

Comment: Move the message from the top of the form to near the button?  It seems like you're trying to drastically over-engineer a simple UX change.

Comment: ohh.. are you using validation plugin ?

Comment: can you show the complete form /

Comment: Hi @David, tks for your suggestion, but it's not possible. I had a restrictly layout and the message must be on the top, for layout purposes.I dont like this too, I preffer a validation with messages directly on each field, but sometimes the layout is the boss.. :D

Comment: @DANIEL: Maybe add a small message next to the button?  So the primary messages are at the top, but next to the button could be something simple like, "Please correct the errors and try again."  The point is, small UX changes are often far simpler than complex functionality changes.  The root of the problem isn't that the page needs to scroll to the top.  The root of the problem is that the user needs an indication that there is an error.  There's more than one way to solve that.

Comment: hi @jaysingkar I want to submit and put the page on the anchor. something like "onclick=location.href='#topform'; submit()" - and YES, I'm using a custom jquery validation.

Comment: @DANIEL sorry my solution it's not ok ?

Comment: @DANIEL Jquery validation that you use give you an error response in the error response call the function toTop. if you wanna other anchor just change 'body' with your anchor. Check my answer.

Comment: Hi @DaebakDo - I'm testing your solution... Only Copy Paste didn't Works.. I dont know why.. I had animate css included on the page, but your solutions doesn't do nothing.. I'm trying to understand your script first (I'm not so experience with java/jquery) - and I'm testing some ideas based on your solution.

Comment: Of coarse that din't work if I can't see your code. what is the part of your validation that give you the error ?

Comment: Which jquery plugin use for validation, formValidation or validate.. or ?

Comment: Hi @DaebakDo I'm using a custom version of the NOTIFYME Jquery Plugin. Its a custom version because the original version is only for 1 email field. - I made a custom in js to put 4 fields and 4 validations. But I think the problem with your script isn't because the validation.  The validation are 100% ok, but the page doesn't goes to the top. (I click on button, with toTop() function, they validate the form, but doesn't go anyway) - I copy-paste your function. But if I put a simple "Alert(msg)"  - to test - replacing the $('html')... code its Works.

Comment: @DANIEL as you see the example work.. your validation code give you an error event well just put the function toTop(); of coarse that you have to change body with the id element where you wanna that the browser sroll.

Comment: @DANIEL yes use the id of your form.

Answer (score 1):

Check this example you can put to top of your form id element.

```js
function toTop() {
    
 $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $( $('body') ).offset().top}, 500, 'swing');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
<form id="contactForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Full name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Phone number</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneNumber" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Email address</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Message</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="7"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" id="captchaOperation"></label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='toTop()'>Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Make a function that scroll to top and than call from your html button element
I don't know if you have the form in main page or where so you have to check the element, but this is the idea:

javascript

```
function toTop() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $( $('body') ).offset().top}, 500, 'swing');
}
```

html

```
<button onclick="toTop()">Click me</button>
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: Hi.. yes.. I'm testing here and I got a similar "ALMOST" solution using this: $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "swing"); - but I cannot indicate the correct anchor - with this I go to the top or I need to configure the right pixel for scrolltop.. and FOR EACH SCREEN SIZE.. (crazy!) -  I'm testing your new solution right now! tks!!!

Comment: @DANIEL ok :) you don't need to adjust the pixel just change 'body' with your form id. Than your validation plugin as some error response for example Jquery form validation as .on('err.form.fv', function(event) {}) well not need to call the function on top from submit button but just inside the error function.

Comment: hi I got the same with your new function.. the original script was missing the 'html body' at start right? Now its Works, but - i cannot configure the anchor.. I put #anchor replacing body?

Comment: Hi! done! just replace the body as you said to #anchor and Works fine.. I upvoted your answer - great!

Answer (score 1):

< a > and < button > do not mix well together, never put them on top of each other.
you could do the simpler and not so elegant solution

```
<button type="submit" onclick="jQuery('#after_submit').click();">
<a id="after_submit" style="display:none;" href="#topform"></a>
```

or do the right thing and go for a scroll function using animate as mentioned above

Comment: great solution! Works fine!